"He who is destined to be hanged will not drown." Can we treat folk wisdom as philosophy?
It is not about religion, it is definitely not science. But folk wisdom often carries some truth confirmed by experience of generations.
Can it be part of philosophical understanding?

Fixed formulas we repeat our of habits without questioning their meaning, whether they contain a kernel of truth or not, is arguably the very opposite of philosophy.

Religion is full of "fixed formulas" yet we do have a philosophy of religion.

If you ask a question about fate, it's definitely philosophy, deterministic physics or the supernatural either way they add up to the same question, Folklore or not it ends with an unresolved answer.

Philosophy is made by people, not by academic degrees (even if academics want you to believe so).

Nice sophism. Philosophy of a thing is not that thing. Religion, in so far as it is fixed formulas and dogma, as you say, is definitely not philosophy.

Your 2-3 line koan-question seems to have all sorts of questions entangled in a short space. Lets see if we can disentangle even some...
1. The specific saying
It's curious — if the saying had been thrown casually in a question centering all the usual fashionable keywords — fate, pre-destination, determinism... it would be respectable. In this form, it's not... What gives?

 Aside: On a site like this one, if someone talks of fatalistically predicting the future it's de jure to be mocked. Even though....

Comes to the question of...
2. Different philosophical styles
Clearly some traditions value tight sayings.
Some don't.
Observe that koan has no translation.
As a style the short-tight poem closest in English is limerick which is synonymous with flippancy; a laugh.
By contrast, the most universal format in Sanskrit is the couplet.
Leads to...
3. Sapir-Whorf

The limits of my language are the limits of my world
Wittgenstein

Also called linguistic relativity.
Languages abilities are actually so different that they are incommensurable in expressive power.
IOW language is not a cloak draped on a pre existing reality so much as mold that encloses it.
This comes to the most central point:
4. Logocentricism

Writing is nothing but the representation of speech; it is bizarre that one gives more care to the determining of the image than to the object.
Rousseau

Derrida expanded on this theme in a manner famously (notoriously) impenetrable:

That the signified is originarily and essentially (and not only for a finite and created spirit) trace, that it is always already in the position of the signifier, is the apparently innocent proposition within which the metaphysics of the logos, of presence and consciousness, must reflect upon writing as its death and its resource

Perhaps the most extreme instance of Logocentricism is not in writing but in music:
In most of the world's people's, music means... well... music.
In the west however, Brendal plays Schubert or Karajan conducts Beethovens 5th.
So music (what others call) is called a performance, a rendering, an interpretation.  The last word is none of these but ... wait for it... a book!
To see how absurd this comes across to us non westerners, here's three Mozarts:
Lang Lang
Gould
Volodos
Why is there this implied bizarre idea that they are all a reflection of the Platonic reality.... which is a book??
AIUI it's because a breathing living tradition is subordinates to ink stains on dead wood.
Compare with Eastern  traditions:

Only that knowledge which issues from the lips of the guru is alive.  Other forms are barren, powerless and the cause if suffering
Shiva Samhita


The guide of those who have no spiritual guide is Satan
Bayazid al Bistami


It is interesting that we feel that human languages vary so much, yet for computer languages (which seem wildly different in expressive power) people fearlessly proclaim that it is all completely equivalent and amounts to a Turing machine. To me, this is like saying that we all think the same because our brains run on glucose. The Mona Lisa is just some minerals, oil and clay smeared on canvas, right? A spirograph is just as expressive.

@ScottRowe this is one of the big lies in CS. But money talks as no CS (or philosophy!) can: zig pays double of php on average

Your answer is very broad, very deep and exquisitely poetic. But you missed the point I was trying to make. The wisdom printed in the Plato and Aristotle inheritance. The wisdom printed in the Bible. All of this wisdom did not go through the filter of dozens of generations (simple people), millions of people in different cultures. Most philosophy and religion were not proven in real life, as was well-known folk wisdom. If simple people through countless generations keep repeating the same saying, it should have some truth in it.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I do believe I got what you're asking. Maybe my expression of the living tradition (without dead 'filters') was insufficient.
I've added something at end of answer. Pls check

@TheMatrixEquation-balance it is possible for something to be neutral, in not having survival value (being true) but not harmful enough to get weeded out. Sometimes people just get attached to things they learned when they were young.

@Rushi - I like it! The dead word (formal written dogma) vs democratic philosophy of time (experience of generations).

@Rushi - "Brendal plays Schubert or Karajan conducts Beethovens 5th" - I like the ancient Greek's view: "Music is the harmony of Heaven".

@ScottRowe, my experience has been that it's usually business-y people saying that. I've never experienced a recreational software developer making that claim. They also know its mathematical truth, of course. But unlike the business-y people, they don't choose to ignore the humanistic falseness of it (referring to your first comment).

Apart from Graecan & Hindu cultures, not much of philosophical thought has survived the test of time for other nations. What passes as folk wisdom however, for various reasons, has made it past the many hurdles philosophy had to face. In such instances, sayings & proverbs have been used to infer their philosophical underpinnings. Perhaps there's little by way of philosophy in folk wisdom, but it's all we have to work on for some peoples. The adage in the OP indicates endorsement of fatalism of some kind for example. Fatalism is a complex concept. Check it out on an encyclopedia, and don't forget to follow the links.
Just as there's reverse mathematics I guess there's reverse philosophy.

I thought that the saying was interesting, I recall hearing it long ago, but no explanation of what it meant. To me it means that there is no point in worrying, because you don't know how things are going to work out, and most likely you will worry about something that never comes to pass.

@ScottRowe, you give as much as you take; hermeneutics has a place for the personal. I latched onto the word "destined". It's a very complex topic (to me). Seems to have ramifications, e.g. stoicism, which I hear is gaining ground in USA (questionable source, mind you).
